# Split Rmarkdown (.Rmd) file into mutiple files (.Rmd)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I made a big Rmarkdown (.Rmd) file that contains only chunks of R codes. I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically generate a (.Rmd) file for every chunk or if I have to manually create a (.Rmd) file for every chunk I have (over 200 chunks).

Let's say I have this (.Rmd) file :

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: '2022-08-13'
---
```

### R Markdown

```
``{r cars}
summary(cars)
``
```

### Including Plots

```
``{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
``
```

Is there a way to generate automatically a (.Rmd) file for the chuck **r cars** and another for the chunk **r pressure**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use package `parsemd`:

```
library(parsermd)

rmd <- parse_rmd("x.Rmd")

rlabels <- c("cars", "pressure")

yaml <- rmd_select(rmd, has_type("rmd_yaml_list"))

for (i in rlabels)
{
  rchunk <- rmd_select(rmd, all_of(i)) 
  sink(paste0(i, ".Rmd"))
  cat(as_document(yaml), sep = "\n")
  cat(as_document(rchunk), sep = "\n")
  sink()  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.. but where is the new (.Rmd) files stored? I couldn't find them...

Comment: They are in your current working directory, as given by `getwd()`.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I was looking for !! It works as intended.